# How do I direct my case view to the shortened URL?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a `<apex:pageBlockTable>` to display a list of cases like this:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!case}" var="c" rows="50" id="cases_table" >
    <apex:column >
        <a target="_parent" href="{!URLFOR($Action.Case.View, c.id)}">{!c.CaseNumber}</a>
            <apex:facet name="header"/>
        </apex:column>
        .
        .
        .
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

When I click on the link to view the case, I get taken to the case page and the URL looks like this:

`https://cs13.salesforce.com/500W0000000oKfFIAU/d?retURL=https%3A%2F%2Fc.cs13.visual.force.com%2Fapex%2FCasesTestPage%3Fsfdc.tabName%3D01rW00000004P7Y`

Instead of directing to that URL, I would instead like to direct to this URL which still displays the case:

`https://cs13.salesforce.com/500W0000000oKfFIAU`

How would I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply change your `<A>` tag to:

`<a target="_parent" href="/{!c.id}">{!c.CaseNumber}</a>`